# OpenCV Face recognition real person

Tags: opencv, iot, face-recognition

Hello i am using face recognition with open cv. The code is from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html). I use my web cam with the raspberry pi and the recognition is ok. When i put my photo in front of the camera then it still detect me.

My questions is how can i check if the face is a real and not an image. I want to use it for smart home door lock/unlock and i dont want anyone with any photo to open the door. Or can i do something with other sensors to ensure that is the real person? Thank you.

Comment: With just a single camera, it'd imagine it would be very difficult, if not impossible (my bet is on that) to differentiate between a person and an image faithfully replicating the scene normally seen by the camera and including the person. On thing that would make this harder to fake would be verifying the background -- does it match with what your camera usually sees? The next step would be working in 3D - LIDAR seems impractical for this purpose, but perhaps stereo vision (2 cameras) could discern between a real 3D person and a photo.

Comment: I would also consider adding further checks, other than just a photo. Some things that come to mind are a fingerprint scan, voice recognition, IR (a picture won't radiate heat like a real person), perhaps even a paired Bluetooth device. Every additional (and independent) test significantly increases the space an attacker would have to search (or replicate) in order to break the algorithm. Note that those are just opinions, I have no experience in this specific area.

Comment: Side note: If you're thinking of using this device to secure your house, you should probably consider the implications this might have on your insurance. I would be suprised if they would consider such device as a sufficient enough security measure without passing some strict tests/certifications. But again, this is just a guess based on my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

An image, once *resampled* (i.e. a picture of a picture) will lose dynamic range.

Check/compare this and/or other artefacts (clipping etc.) you may notice that come about from the resampling that aren't in a standard image.

You may have to turn off any auto-iris, auto-gain, auto-everything on your camera...

Answer (score 0):

You can use emotion recognition using Microsoft azure or affectiva or voice recognition

** note: Voice recognition is not secure enough as he may spoof the camera with playing video and play a sound or he can talk to the recorder, you'll not be able to verify that he is the person